How to call $display from DPI-C function
I have some C++ code running in a SystemVerilog simulator via DPI-C. The C++ code is an imported function, so it can only call other functions - not tasks.
I would like to call the SystemVerilog task $display (or $info, $error, etc) from this code in order to log some messages and have them nicely integrated with the simulator (it can show them in the waves etc.).
Unfortunately $display etc. are tasks, not functions, so I can't call them directly. You can do this:
export "DPI-C" function sv_info;
function void sv_info(input string message);
    fork
        $info(message);
    join_none
endfunction

Which almost works. It prints all the messages but because we've forked a load of new tasks they happen in an arbitrary order within the same time step, so the order of your messages gets screwed up.
Is there any way to work around this? The only way I can think to do it is to collate all the messages in a queue, sort them according to right order, and then print them all at the end of the time step. But I don't think it's possible to explicitly schedule an SV task to run after everything else.

You can certainly put a $display in a function. System tasks are improperly named functions. The IEEE 1800-2023 SystemVerilog LRM has a clarification in section 5.6.3 System tasks and system functions that says

SystemVerilog defines a standard set of system tasks and system functions in this document (see Clause 20
and Clause 21). Unlike SystemVerilog tasks (see 13.3), these standard system tasks do not consume time and
can be used in the same places void functions (see 13.4) can be used.

Also, within your DPI imported C/C++ code, you can call the SystemVerilog VPI routine vpi_printf() which sends its output to the log file. The only difference is the format string uses C printf formatting instead of $display formatting.

Interesting, I think this is a bug in Questa then. I was wondering why they were tasks...

Works for me in Questa

Ah you're right. I could have sworn it gave me an error when I called it from DPI-C. Weird.

A mailbox seems to do the trick!
mailbox #(string) message_mailbox = new;

initial begin
    automatic string message;
    forever begin
        message_mailbox.get(message);
        $info(message);
    end
end

export "DPI-C" function sv_info;
function void sv_info(input string message);
    message_mailbox.try_put(message);
endfunction

